# rails console require nokogiri return false (but works in irb)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

My environment is `ruby 1.9.3p327` and `rails 3.2.8` on a mac.

I add the gem `nokogiri` to my `Gemfile`. Run `bundle install` command. The command show me `Using nokogiri (1.5.5)` and the `gem list` command return `nokogiri (1.5.5)`.

In the rails console `require 'nokogiri'` return `false` but in `irb` it  return `true`.

How is this possible?

Comment: Are you using `bundle exec rails console`?

Comment: No.  Tried but don't work either.

Comment: Is it possible it's already loaded? Give it a try.

Comment: If you're in the rails console, you don't need to `require 'nokogiri'`; it's been required for your by Rails. Just start using it.

Answer (score 37):

According to the first two lines of [the API documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require), `require` will:

- return `true` if load successful
- return `false` if already loaded
- raise `LoadError` if file cannot be found

Since Rails console loads your gems, Nokogiri was probably required earlier. Irb doesn't do that.